# Multiple delete in Microsoft Outlook Web Access

Tags: exchange, outlook-web-access

How can I delete multiple or all inbox messages in the Microsoft Outlook Web Access 2003?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you try logging into your OWA with some other browser than Internet Explorer or Firefox ?

Opera for instance is not *fully* supported which can actually be a good thing since you don't get all that fancy Outlook imitation. The interface is much simpler and functionalities are much more available. You should then get a "check all" and be able to delete with increased speed.

Else, best solution would still probably to be able to configure and connect an Outlook client to your OWA...

Comment: The best way is to connect Outlook client.

Answer (score 1):

If using OWA 2007 (I do not have 2003 installed to test) there should just be some checkboxes that you can tick to affect multiple items, then just click delete.

[image]

(OWA 2007 on Firefox)

If you are using OWA 2003 or 2007 in Internet Explorer, I believe that you can hold down shift to highlight multiple items in order or control to select multiple items that are separate to each other.

Comment: It's OWA 2003 and shift does not work. I need to delte about 8000 messages.

Comment: Odd. Ctrl-click and Shift-click work as expected for me using OWA on Exchange 2003

Answer (score 0):

<kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>click</kbd> does work — but only if you don't scroll too far.

I find I can get about two screenfuls of scrolling for each chunk added to the selection.

If you go too far by mistake, it's not a problem, just scroll back up a little closer and try again.  You *can* scroll back to the top to verify the selection is still intact without losing what you've done.  It's possible that zooming out (<kbd>cmd</kbd>-<kbd>-</kbd>) helps, but only a little bit, even if you zoom a lot.  (It seemed like I could pick up maybe 10 more items per click.)

None of the other solutions here or in a [near-duplicate question](https://superuser.com/questions/150644/bulk-deleting-all-messages-in-a-folder-in-microsoft-outlook-web-access) worked for me, though my case was slightly different (selecting in order to move, rather than delete messages).   I tried using Opera, <kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>click</kbd> or <kbd>Cmd</kbd>-<kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>click</kbd> to select the whole range at once, or most frustratingly <kbd>Cmd</kbd>-<kbd>A</kbd>.