# Bulk Deleting All Messages in a Folder in Microsoft Outlook Web Access

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2007, outlook-web-access

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Multiple delete in Microsoft Outlook Web Access](https://superuser.com/questions/52067/multiple-delete-in-microsoft-outlook-web-access)

How do you delete all messages in a folder in Outlook, preferrably through Web Access?

I left my Outlook account unattended for several days (on vacation) and when I got back I found several folders with over 5k emails, mostly error logging or spam. When I try to open the Outlook client, it just locks up, presumably unable to download that many emails. I can view at most 100 emails at a time, but I can't select all emails to delete or permanently delete them immediately, so manually deleting this many emails is going to take a while.

Gmail has a similar feature to select and delete all emails in a folder, and that's free so I figure being a quality non-free product from Microsoft, Outlook should have a similar feature (yes that's sarcasm). I've Googled, but I'm not finding anything. Is this possible?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

**UPDATE**

Just right click on the desired folder and select `Empty Folder`

[image]

---

<strike>Like [dean](https://superuser.com/questions/150644/bulk-deleting-all-messages-in-a-folder-in-microsoft-outlook-web-access/150648#150648) said, you can hold <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> to select single items or even <kbd>Shift</kbd> to select multiple items.</strike>

I haven't used OWA in a long time but a little trick I used to do in Firefox was to use this javascript bit to select all of the checkboxes

> javascript:var f=document.activeElement.childNodes[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PkEeQ.jpg).contentDocument;var c=f.all['MsgID'];var i;for(i=0;i

type it in the address bar and hit enter, it should select all of the checkboxes.

Comment: Selecting multiple items isn't the problem. Checking the top-most checkbox selects/unselects all on the page. The problem is OWA only shows you a maximum of 100 emails. Javascript can't select emails that aren't listed on the page.

Comment: my bad, updated my original answer

Comment: hmm... I'm using outlook 2007 and I don't have that option unless I'm right-clicking the "deleted items" folder.  Is there some other way for other folders?  If I try to select all messages in a folder using control-a (17,000+ messages) and then right click on the messages or press <delete>, outlook becomes unresponsive.

Comment: nvm, control-a, control-d cleared it out.

Comment: I'm on a Linux system running Chrome, and right-clicking just opens the browser's context menu.

Answer (score 1):

I know that you can hold Control and select the items and then hit the delete button. You could try that.

Answer (score 1):

While in your inbox, hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>. This will select all messages in your inbox. Do the same in your deleted folder to permanently delete the messages.

**Warning! This will delete ALL messages!**

Comment: Didn't work

­­­­

Comment: This does work if you delete (using the delete key, etc.) *after* you CTRL+A.